# How to run requirments.txt through jenkins using docker?

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

Hi i am new to Jenkins i have repository i clone it first , then i need to build the image using Dockerfile it also include the `requirments.txt`. When i run `requirments.txt` file from my `build.sh` file it works fine but when i run it through jenkins using pipeline like this :

```
pipeline {
    agent any 
    stages {
        stage('Build') { 
            steps {
                sh 'sudo bash /home/salman/mlops/build.sh'
           }
}
        
    }
}
```

it throw this error:

```
Step 1/6 : FROM ubuntu:latest
 ---> 9873176a8ff5
Step 2/6 : RUN apt-get update   && apt-get install -y python3-pip python3-dev   && cd /usr/local/bin   && ln -s /usr/bin/python3 python   && pip3 install --upgrade pip
 ---> Using cache
 ---> e5f345c76347
Step 3/6 : WORKDIR mlcode
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 273bf7d60f31
Step 4/6 : COPY requirments.txt .
COPY failed: file not found in build context or excluded by .dockerignore: stat requirments.txt: file does not exist
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
ERROR: script returned exit code 1
Finished: FAILURE
```

even i check the path of `requirments.txt` file its correct but it didn't run from jenkins. This is my `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM ubuntu:latest
RUN apt-get update \
  && apt-get install -y python3-pip python3-dev \
  && cd /usr/local/bin \
  && ln -s /usr/bin/python3 python \
  && pip3 install --upgrade pip
WORKDIR mlcode
COPY requirments.txt .
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirments.txt
CMD ["python3", "/mlcode/code.py"]
```

and this is my `build.sh`:

```
if cat /home/salman/mlops/Mlops/mlcode/code.py | grep sklearn ; then

sudo docker build -t mlcontainer -f /home/salman/mlops/Dockerfile .

elif cat /home/salman/mlops/Mlops/mlcode/code.py | grep keras ; then

sudo docker build -t dlcontainer -f /home/salman/mlops/Dockerfile .

else

echo "Code not found";

fi
```

Comment: Are you sure it's not `requirements.txt`? Are you sure the file itself is committed to the repository? Normally you let Jenkins clone the repo, and the file should be part of the repo.

Comment: yes the file is present in repo.

Comment: https://github.com/Moiz-Ali-Moomin/MLOpsTask3/ this is the repo i am using.

Comment: "`sh 'sudo bash /home/salman/mlops/build.sh'`" Check that the directory where the script is running from, is the same directory with the `requirments.txt` file. Your bash script is using absolute paths to the your Dockerfile, but the Dockerfile itself expects `requirements.txt` to be in the current directory.

Comment: all the repos code and build.sh is in the same directory.

Comment: Looking at the repository, the file name `requirements.txt` does in fact have an `e` after the second `r`; double-check the spelling in the `RUN pip install` line.